# Google sheets app script regex not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a regex match working in sheets app scripts.  It basically checks a text string with a shortened version of the text sting.  Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
var found = new RegExp("/Peter/").test("Peter Haworth");
```

The found variable returns false.

I have tried this on regexr.com and it correctly matches "Peter".

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The slashes are matching actual slashes because they are in a string. Slashes are for RegExp literals, e.g. `/Peter/.test('...')`.

Comment: RegExp might also not be necessary. Why not use `'...'.includes(shortstring)`?

Comment: Thanks, removing the slashes fixed it.  For some reason, I thought the slashes were required, probably because the regexr.com website includes them.

Comment: I'll also look into using includes() since that feels like a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove the forward slashes

```
function lfunko() {
  let s = "Peter Peter Pumpkin eater";
  let re = new RegExp('Peter','g');//forward slashes remove
  Logger.log(re.test(s));
  let re1 = new RegExp('/Peter/','g');
  Logger.log(re1.test(s));
  let re2 = /Peter/;//parenthesis removed
  Logger.log(re2.test(s));
}

Execution log
2:14:51 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:14:50 PM  Info    true
2:14:50 PM  Info    false
2:14:50 PM  Info    true
2:14:52 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your regex without the "?

`var found = new RegExp(/Peter/).test("Peter Haworth");`